# How can I send a parse push to an installation id or device token

Tags: parse-platform

How can I use the Parse REST API to push to a specific deviceToken or installation Id?  I make the request and it succeeds with a 200 response but I get no push.

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XYZ" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: FOO" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "deviceToken": "someId"
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "Willie Hayes injured by own pop fly."
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```